# How to make a SCHEDULED and DEADLINE'd todo only show up once in agenda-view in emacs org-mode

Tags: emacs, lisp, elisp, org-mode

In org mode, if you create a todo, and first assign it a DEADLINE, maybe a week in advance, then a few days later, get around to scheduling it, both the SCHEDULED todo and the DEADLINE todo show up in my agenda. How do I get rid of the DEADLINE item? It clutters up my agenda view.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is a specific variable for that that was introduced in commit `8d6aa8f3` (2010-02-17).  This should put it somewhere around version 6.35.

> org-agenda-skip-deadline-prewarning-if-scheduled is a variable defined
>   in `org-agenda.el'. Its value is nil
>
> Documentation: Non-nil means skip deadline prewarning when entry is
>   also scheduled. This will apply on all days where a prewarning for the
>   deadline would be shown, but not at the day when the entry is actually
>   due.  On that day, the deadline will be shown anyway. This variable
>   may be set to nil, t, or a number which will then give the number of
>   days before the actual deadline when the prewarnings should resume.
>   This can be used in a workflow where the first showing of the deadline
>   will trigger you to schedule it, and then you don't want to be
>   reminded of it because you will take care of it on the day when
>   scheduled.
>
> You can customize this variable.

I couldn't spot it in the manual however `M-x apropos RET org-agenda-skip-` does list it as well as other variables that offer similar sorts of filtering.

Comment: Hi Jonathan, I hope you see this message. I've been searching everywhere on how to "customize a variable" for hours but couldn't find a simple guide. Most tutorials simply say "set this variable to t" or "change the variable to nil", but how/where do I do that? Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: @RandomCertainty you can use `M-x customize-variable` and specify the exact variable, or use the `customize` interface and browse to it.  Otherwise you can use `(setq org-agenda-skip-deadline-prewarning-if-scheduled <value>)` in `init.el`